# Higher voltage trimmer in low voltage RF receiver

Tags: capacitor, rf, analog, identification, mixer

For tuning the local oscillator/mixer IC SA602 in my 20MHz RF receiver, I need trimmers of range 4pF to 40pF and 3pF to 20pF. The power source is 12 V. The lowest voltage rating of trimmers available is  25 V. But I want to know if it is ok to use a 100 V or 250 V rated ones.

Comment: Of course it is.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with a higher voltage rated trimmer component may be it's bulkier or more expensive.

If the rated capacitance is the same, and the frequency range is OK, then higher permitted voltage is no problem.